# SQL Server OR statement with AND

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this

```
select * 
from MyTable
where (@Param is null or (FieldCode = 'Whatever' and FieldValue like '%' + @Param + '%'))
```

As I'm adding more statements to my where clause, my query is slowing down. I think it's because it's evaluating the AND part before the OR (which contains a LIKE, which can be slow). I want it to skip the query with the AND if @Param is null, how should i do this?

Comment: It's depends upon various factors , better check your execution plan .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this for better performance:

```
select * 
from MyTable
where @Param is null or case when @Param is not null and FieldCode = 'Whatever' 
then case when FieldValue like '%' + @Param + '%' then 1 end end = 1
```

This will prevent the heavy wildchar compare when it isn't necessary

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest you check your indexes you are definitely missing one then.
Beside of that do you really need to use every column? Use (NOLOCK) for reading data.
Furthermore like is very bad for indexes look if you would really need the first % for your program or if you could search for the data on the clientside (Filter a larger subset of data)

Comment: Yeah I am actually using CONTAINS where possible instead of LIKE

Comment: Don't *ever* use NOLOCK for reading production data unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: Well you can use NOLOCK in most cases where you have a table with none/few updates (hence the ''reading data'') or where you are not reliant on the consistence of your selected data.

Answer (score 0):

You could always break it apart and just do a different select statement if the @param is null.

```
If @Param is not null
    select * 
    from MyTable
    where (FieldCode = 'Whatever' and FieldValue like '%' + @Param + '%')
Else
    select *
    from MyTable
```